# Splitting a a string into a list of items in pandas dataframe | Python | Pandas |

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe where column values like:

```
0    ['note' 'pen']
1    ['paper' 'pencil']
2    ['note' 'pen']
```

I want to make the values in column, that contain a list of all different items that is get after splitting each values.

Expected Output:

```
0   [note, pen]
1   [paper, pencil]
2   [note, pen]
```

I try the below method, but i not getting the expected output:

```
df_['products'] = [list(map(str, i.split())) for i in df_['products']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to make [numpy arrays into lists](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)?

```
df_['products'].apply(lambda x: x.to_list())
```